# How to create an entry from plugin controller?

Tags: plugin-development

Let's say I have a section 'foo', with following fields and slug:

First Name (name)

Last Name (lname)

Plan (plan)

Cost (cost)

The field cost is dynamically created by a function already present in controller. I tried the following:

```
public function actionGetCost()
{
    $fname = craft()->request->getParam('name');
    $lname = craft()->request->getParam('lname');
    $plan = craft()->request->getParam('plan');

    ...

    $entry = new EntryModel();
    $entry->sectionId = 16;
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date('n-j-Y') ;
    $entry->postDate = $date;
    $entry->authorId = 1;
    $entry->enabled = true;
    $entry->setContentFromPost([
       'name' => $fname,
       'lname' => $lname,
       'plan' => $plan,       
       'cost' => $cost->id,
    ]);

    $save = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);

    if ($save){
      echo "saved" !
    }else{
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($entry()->getAllErrors());
      echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

What's wrong in the code? How can I do it?

Comment: Have you checked out the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin? If you go into the controllers and service files that could give you some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Damon mentions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/how-to-create-an-entry-from-plugin-controller#comment28156_20995), I'd highly recommend checking out the Guest Entries plugin.

Specifically the private [`_populateEntryModel()`](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/how-to-create-an-entry-from-plugin-controller#comment28156_20995) method which creates the `EntryModel` class and gives a good example of the properties that are necessary to set to before calling `EntriesService->saveEntry()`.

Comment: Thanks that helped me !! I have updated the question with the correct working code.